# Should I delete my own questions if I use SO to get unstuck when nobody else is around?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, moderation

Some community members think this question is not about programming and ought to be closed. So I wonder what has changed. I have been a member for almost 6 years now and it did not used to be like this!

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27289038/unordered-map-does-not-work) yesterday and received a very insightful comment that helped me solve the problem. Now given specific nature of my problem I may chose to delete the question myself since it may be of little use to anyone else or I may keep it around with a reasonable self answer as encourage by @Yakk (in this case).

OK, on further inspection I can tell that actual reason to close this question precisely is:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Which is fine. It's really a good thing and I stand by this. I'm new to the meta discussion so I'm not really sure what the vibe here is but what I've been missing is a way for people to redeem themselves.

I can actually turn this around and make something useful out of this. The fact of the matter is that the problem was due to the way I was tracking memory not the implementation and I was absolutely sure that I was using the stuff incorrectly (which I was) but I jump between different languages and environments so much that I sometimes forget details, like I assumed that the key was copied as soon as I put it in the map but we don't need to just close them we need to rewrite them or channel them in a form that's more useful to SO members.

Like this [Condition Variables C#/.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657637/condition-variables-c-net) I had an insightful experience working with conditional variables and it turned into a rather nice little example which turned into a wiki entry instead and it appears to be appreciated by some people.

Can't we figure out a way to funnel or encourage people to better themselves and rewrite questions that don't make sense to the community into things that do?

Comment: *Can't we figure out a way to funnel or encourage people to better themselves and rewrite questions that don't make sense to the community into things that do?* Putting a post on hold is *not the end of the road*. You can still improve the post and have it reopened. **Closing is not the end of the road**. However, the sheer volume of new posts every single day mean that the *community as a whole* can no longer do that work.

Comment: @MartijnPieters which surely must feel discouraging to new users. I get that, I even have moderation privileges for my years of service. Some questions do need to be closed but when a question gets closed, it isn't clear how you get back from there, is it? Can say I spend much time working on closed questions but I'd rather see that we put questions in limbo with a clear indication of what you should do to redeem yourself and if you do, maybe even award some extra reputation for that but that implies that a bunch of people thought it was worth reviving the question.

Comment: A question is **put on hold** at first. A post that has been put on hold has a notice on it as to why it was put on hold, and that notice includes pointers as to how to remedy that. Only if a post then isn't improved and (automatically) enters the reopen queue and then reopened, is the notice changed to *closed*.

Comment: Your question *body* here is okay, but your question *title* makes rather sweeping assumptions as to why questions are being voted to close. There are *excellent* reasons to aggressively vote to close; there are loads of questions that  attract a lot of low-quality answers if not closed promptly for example. I'd not make assumptions about the reasons for the current policies on community moderation.

Comment: votes down and close could be an (over)reaction to rather poorly presented self-answer. If one only quickly skims it, it may misread as something like "oh I there was a simple mistake / typo, forget it". (agree with @MartijnPieters that question title could also use some love)

Comment: Sounds like you are suffering from a stage 1 case of CPPIP.  Aka, C++ Induced Paranoia, the more experienced the programmer the harder they fall.  That feeling of dread when a standard library class gives you an undebuggable problem and realizing that the project deadline you promised was a wild underestimate and the next month is going to be hell. Writing an SO post on the dangers of temporaries can be cathartic, but is a tall order given how many books already warn about this.  And maybe you've got something more important to do right now :)

Comment: @HansPassant we all must learn somehow but I see you point.

Comment: @HansPassant somewhat off-topic but what the hell. Is it wrong to use the SO community to perform a sanity check on your work when no co-worker is around?

Comment: @gant to be clear, are we talking about this question here no or the question that I linked? I do agree that the title of this question right here on meta SO is more provocative or misleading than anything else and maybe I should change it.

Comment: @JohnLeidegren It is wrong to use the SO community as a sanity check.

Comment: @Louis I guess it depends on what I mean by sanity check. I should have been more specific but this was exactly why I joined SO all those years ago. It was a place to discuss practical problems and actual solutions and you could get wonderful answers from people who wasn't your coworkers or like minded friends in mere minutes. It's a place to get unstuck for sure. And this must be allowed, must it not?

Comment: @JohnLeidegren Everything you mention is fine but *secondary* to the goal of building a library of quality questions and answers. One metric for question quality is how likely a question is to be useful to others. A common example of a question that fails this check is a question where the problem is caused by a typo. Such questions should be closed and deleted. That the OP was helped is no reason to keep the question around. That friendships formed because of the question is no reason to keep it around. If a friendship ends because a question that does not belong was closed, then so be it.

Comment: Great. 12 downvotes and no constructive criticism. I'm trying to learn here...

Comment: @Louis I'm fine with that and I will delete my question though I managed to get it on hold now instead.

Comment: @JohnLeidegren On Meta, downvotes often mean not 'I think the post is badly made' but rather 'I would answer the question(s) in the post with a _no_'. I guess that's what happened here. It's when votes escape Meta and start impacting non-Meta posts where we assume they _do_ mean the former - as happens all too often - that there's a problem.

Answer (score 13):

> Can't we figure out a way to funnel or encourage people to better
>   themselves and rewrite questions that don't make sense to the
>   community into things that do?

That's exactly what closing a question does. Once (if) it's improved with an edit it will go into the re-open queue. Closing != deleting.

I can't really think of any better way to encourage people to improve a question than putting it on hold, thus preventing any more answers until the question is fixed.

Comment: "That's exactly what closing a question does." Maybe that is the idea you have in mind, but many of us find closing to be a heavy *de*motivator. Having something closed because someone disagrees about quality is a surefire way to discourage many of us from improving _anything_, let alone that specific question at hand. Maybe that is because of a disconnect between how you (and possibly many mods) view closing and how many of us view closing. A close does not look and feel like a suggestion to improve; it looks and feels like a punishment. We don't come here for negative reinforcement.

Answer (score 4):

> Can't we figure out a way to funnel or encourage people to better themselves and rewrite questions that don't make sense to the community into things that do?

There are two groups who *can* do this.  There is the original poster of the question, and there are the random community people who try to improve it.

Improving a question isn't easy.  It can often take several minutes of correcting grammar, spelling, formatting, and possibly even rewriting the question. To truly fix something it can even take longer (making your own MCVE for the question if you feel you know what is being asked).

Just giving a comment [isn't enough to motivate people to update the question](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13900826#13900826).

On the other hand, casting a close vote is something that *can* motivate the original poster to improve the question.  In theory, they can fix their own questions much faster than someone else because they already know what the problem they are having - they've got the code in front of them (if they don't, then thats a problem in its own right).

The community that fixes questions is overwhelmed with poor quality questions.  The way to help this community is to [do more](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=all) help spread out the load (and not leave it all on those people who do it currently) - there's even a [badge for it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/223/copy-editor).  The way to motivate those people is to help them by doing it too.

It also helps to close the questions that are crap so that the people who *do* fix questions and answers don't have to deal with as much crap in the first place.

Though, casting a close vote and moving on is also a way to motivate people (the original poster) to fix the question that they are interested in.

To this end, join the ranks of those who do edits on questions and fix them up and join the rans of those who are active in the close vote, first post, and low quality review queues.  When there is crap, close it.  When there is something that should get fixed posted by a new user, help fix it.  When there is something awful in VLQ, vote to delete it (if its not awful, fix it).

<sup><sub>Please don't take this personally</sub></sup>

People get *demotivated* when there are people who complain about the quality on the site and suggest that *other* people do things when there are very few votes, reviews or revisions on the profile showing that they too are in the there trying to keep the site clean.

Comment: ... and he left us.